# how to use keyword 'raw' in apply() to a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, apply

According to pandas 0.18.1 documentation, apply() function has a keyword argument 'raw':

> raw : boolean, default False
>   If False, convert each row or column into a Series. If raw=True the passed function will receive ndarray objects instead. If you are just applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve much better performance
>   (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

I know that apply() function can be used to both DataFrame objects and GroupBy objects. I tried to prove that 'raw=True' can improve performance and I found that 'raw=True' seems to be only accessible to DataFrame objects but not GroupBy objects.

Here is what I tried:

```
# df3 is used to manipulate    
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    def classify(x):
    if x > 0.3:
        return 'A'
    else:
        return 'B'
df3['type'] = map(classify, df3['col1'])
def classify_2(x):
    if x > 1.0:
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'D'
df3['type2'] = map(classify_2, df3['col1'])

setup = "from __main__ import df3; import numpy as np"
print timeit("df3[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(np.std, raw=True)",setup=setup,number=1000)        
print timeit("df3[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(np.std)", setup=setup,number=1000)
```

the result prints: `1.12559700012 1.4388859272`
so 'raw=True' can improve performance indeed.
But when I tried `df3.groupby('type')[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(np.sum, raw=True)`, Python 2.7 raises a TypeError:

> TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'

But `df3.groupby('type')[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(np.sum)` can still work as usual.

Can anybody tell me what went wrong? Or did 'raw=True' just cannot be applied to a GroupBy object?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Those are (DataFrame.apply and GroupBy.apply) two different methods.  Check the docs for GroupBy.apply [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

Comment: Thx for your reply. But I still get confused by the way `Groupby.apply()` is used. It seems that `Groupby.apply()` tries to pass `raw=True` as a keyword argument of np.sum. To test this, I tried `df3.groupby('type')[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(np.std, ddof=1)` because `ddof` is a keyword argument of `np.sum()` but not `Groupby.apply()` . As a result, the code worked  justifying my guess. And if I tried `df3[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(np.std, ddof=1)`, it also worked. So Both `DataFrame.apply()` and `Groupby.apply()` tries to pass `ddof=1` to `np.std()`.  Could you please tell me why? Thx~

Comment: Sorry I am afraid I didn't get your question. For all functions you pass to apply, you also have the option to pass their parameters. It is not specific to numpy. It would have worked if you defined that function too.

Comment: You are right! I never noticed this attribute of `apply()`. So the keyword arguments appearing in `apply()` can be either applied to `apply()`  itself like `raw=True` or the function passed to `apply()`, am  I correct? This being said, `raw=True` can only be applied to `DataFrame.apply()` but cannot be applied to `GroupBy.apply()`, am I right?  Thanks for your help :)